# Logic about systems?

Tags: reference-request, logic, notation

In Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, his theorem is about a system of logic. Where can I find more about this study, especially the notation?

EDIT

I mean logic about systems in general. I worded the above a bit wrong.

Comment: It will not be much fun, the system is Principia, not current first-order logic. Also, he leaves out most of the detail.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's a bit misleading. Gödel 1931 explicitly shows that his argument applies to *any* formal theory satisfying certain very general conditions (as we would put it, the system is primitive-recursively axiomatized and represents all primitive recursive functions). And the detail for this general version of the First Theorem is all there.

Comment: Do you want to learn about formal logical systems or Godel's theorem?

Comment: Formal Logic Systems. Not any in particular, just in general. I do know that Gödel's theorems dealt with them in general. That is why I referenced his work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *Gödel Without Tears* freely downloadable at http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/gwt/GWT.pdf

Or get out of the library a copy of my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*.